# Looking for a CA key value storage with CAS support

Tags: mongodb, replication, consistency, voldemort

I'm looking for a persistent key value storage that supports consistency, availability and compare-and-set.

It will be deployed on three nodes and must be operable when one (any) of nodes is down. If the whole cluster goes offline (due to a power problems for an example) and then is back online it shouldn't lose any data. Also I expect the system not to bother a system administrator unless two nodes are down. Of cause it is desirable to be as fast as it possible. And the most important feature is consistency: if something is reported to be saved it can't be lost due to a failure.

I explored MongoDB's [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/#rollbacks) that in some rare situation it requires manual intervention, but it's not optional.

Another system I looked over was [Voldemort](http://www.project-voldemort.com/voldemort/). I assume it meets my requirements with following settings:

```
<replication-factor>3</replication-factor>
<required-reads>2</required-reads>
<required-writes>2</required-writes>
```

but it doesn't provide comprehensive docs about replication and consistency, so I can't verify my assumption.

Do you have an experience with a storage that fits my requirements? Could you recommend me something?

P.S. I'm not intent to store huge amount of information, so sharding may be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MongoDB with a Write Concern of 'majority', then you will never lose data, and you will never have a rollback.

The Write Concern of 'majority' (or of '2' in a three-node replica set) will perform the equivalent of the 'required-writes' 2 in Voldemort.

Reference:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/replication/#replica-set-write-concern
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getLastError/

Comment: Are you sure? It seems that write propagation just override the data that should be rollbacked, therefore rollback is not necessary, but if no writes follow described failure we still have one node (rejoined former primary) in inconsistent state and when it again becomes primary we can have problems.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  MongoDB only ever has one master (primary) node at one time.  This is the only node that can ever receive writes.  If the primary node fails, the most up-to-date secondary node takes over.  If all writes are done with 'majority' Write Concern, the most up-to-date secondary is guaranteed to have all writes stored in it.  Rollbacks only happen when there are writes on the (former) primary that were not propagated to the most up-to-date secondary.  With a Write Concern of 'majority', rollbacks can never happen.